# Integration testing async DOM event handlers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing

I've inherited a decent number of integration tests which simulate mouse/touch events against DOM elements and assert application state periodically while the resulting action is performed.

A common problem throughout these tests is a failure to wait for the full completion of async behavior resulting in unintended side-effects.

Consider the following:

```js
const LoadState = {
  Pending: 'pending',
  Loaded: 'loaded',
  Failed: 'failed'
};

const App = {
  state: {
    loadState: LoadState.Pending,
    renderAnimationFrameId: null
  },
  
  ui: {
    loadState: document.getElementById('load-state'),
    loadButton: document.getElementById('load-button')
  },
  
  initialize() {
    this._load = this._load.bind(this);
    this.ui.loadButton.addEventListener('click', this._load);
  },
  
  render() {
    // Throttle rendering to framerate.
    if (this.state.renderAnimationFrameId) {
      return;
    }
  
    this.state.renderAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.ui.loadState.textContent = this.state.loadState;
      this.state.renderAnimationFrameId = null;
    });
  },
  
  _load() {
    window.fetch(new Request('flowers.jpg')).then(({ ok }) => {
      this.state.loadState = ok ? LoadState.Loaded : LoadState.Failed;
    }).catch(() => {
      this.state.loadState = LoadState.Failed;
    }).finally(() => {
      this.render();
    });
  }
};

App.initialize();
App.render();
```

```html
<input id='load-button' type="button" value="Load Data" />

<div id='load-state'>
  Pending
</div>
```

Assuming a mocked implementation of `fetch`, I would like to verify that `load-button` reacts properly to being clicked and that `App` properly updates afterward. Something like this is written fairly intuitively:

```
window.fetch = Promise.resolve(true);
describe('App', () => {
    App.initialize();

    it('should load', (done) => {
        App.ui.loadButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

        // Wait for event to update state after fetch resolution.
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(App.state.loadState === LoadState.Loaded);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should render', (done) => {
        App.render();

        // Wait for throttled render
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(App.state.renderAnimationFrameId === null);
            expect(App.ui.loadState.textContent === LoadState.Loaded);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

These tests introduce a subtle bug. The first test has partially waited, but not fully waited, for App's asynchronous logic to settle.The test passes because `state.loadState` is correct, but a call to `render` is still in-flight. The second test may exhibit erratic results due to this.

I'm wondering what appropriate responses to this might be. Some proposed solutions include:

- Mock `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame` and enqueue their callbacks instead of executing asynchronously. Allow for synchronous play-forward of callbacks. Very magical & error-prone solution, promises still asynchronous and need to be handled separately
- Rewrite production code to ensure all pending promises are publicly exposed. This makes using `async` and `await` much more challenging and unintuitive.
- Spy on `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame`, and `Promise` , try to infer what async behavior is still pending as a result of a method being ran, determine async resolution by polling spies. This is less complex than the above, but race conditions and third-party code becomes more difficult to debug, and unclear how using `await` or `yield` would work.

Maybe there are other options? Basically it's unclear whether it should be the app's responsibility to make async functionality exposed properly, or if the burden is fully on the testing environment. If on the testing environment, does it make sense to fully control async behavior, or is a strictly reactionary approach preferred?

TL;DR: Mouse/touch event handlers are async and have no need to expose their internals. What's an appropriate response in order to support testing needs?